# Kendo Grid Popup with Tabstrip

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am try to to put the tabstrip inside a grid's popup but the template is not working.

Please help by creating sample on JSFiddle.

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is customary to post the code you have tried as part of your question, if you can, since it lets others know you've at least attempted to solve your own problem. It also gives people a starting point, meaning they're more likely to answer your question! Try creating a Fiddle of your own :)

Comment: Create a demo on JSFiddle.

Comment: @Anup
http://jsbin.com/IvOvUje/3/edit

I am refering this example and same i am implementing using jsp wrappers but template is showing error in jsp.

Answer (score 1):

I hope, it's help you: http://www.telerik.com/forums/tabstrip-content-inside-edit-template

Download code: [KendoPopupEditorWithTabStrip.zip](http://www.telerik.com/clientsfiles/ce9f2864-9e5f-4a70-aa73-ab77a862eab2_KendoPopupEditorWithTabStrip.zip?sfvrsn=0)